# Field Level Permission Leakage to a profile

Tags: custom-field, permissions, fields, field-level-security, lookup-field

[image]

I have a Recruiter profile Which has field level permission for "Assigned Owner Field" is given only Visible Persmisson.But when a user Logins who is assigned Recruiter Profile is able to edit the field.

[image]

Comment: does the running user also have a permission set granting Edit access of the field?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user with the Recruiter profile has the [**"Transfer Record"**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_transfer.htm&type=5) permission. Transfer Record permission allows the user to change the owner of any record they own or have access to, regardless of the field level permission.

You can [remove](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385539&language=en_US&type=1) the **"Transfer Record"** permission from the Recruiter profile or create a validation rule to prevent the user from changing the owner field.

Comment: Assigned owner field is a custom field having lookup to user object. It is not a standard owner field